# Search Form Not Working In Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, search

For some reason my search form is not working correctly when my app is launched, in the localhost its working without a problem but when I go to use the search on the launched app the search seems to be broken. I can't figure out why, I followed the Railscasts Simple Search Form to implement it and it hasn't been a problem in local at all.

My user model looks like

```
   def self.search(search)
     if search
       find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
     else
       find(:all)
     end
   end
```

My users controller index looks like

```
   def index
     @users = User.search(params[:search])
     @title = "All Users"

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.json { render :json => @users }
     end
   end
```

My user index view

```
 <% form_tag users_path, :method => 'get' do %>
   <p>
     <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
     <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
   </p>
 <% end %>

 <ul class="users">
   <%= render @users %>
 </ul>
```

Not only is the search not working correctly but when I type a name and its not there it should return all users but instead it returns an empty page, not sure if thats relevant but I thought I'd be as through as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am assuming that you are using MySQL for development and heroku's PostgreSQL for production. Normally errors like this are probably due to differences in production and development database environments.

The problem could be the statement

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
```

change it to this

```
find(:all, :conditions => ['name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
```

notice the ILIKE.

Always best to use same database in development and production, as this will prevent problems later on. Also checkout the heroku docs [here](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database#common_issues_migrating_to_postgresql). if you are using heroku. Hope it helps

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Just out of curiousity how did you guys know I was using Heroku, was it because of the PostgreSQL type error?

Comment: @Michael glad to help, i had a similar problem once before your problem had a similar symptom thats how i guessed you were using heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a hosting provider or are you running the app in 'production' on a local server? If you are using Heroku, Heroku uses Postgres which can handle sql queries differenly. To test you could setup Postgres in your dev environment and check the results of your queries.